# Problem with preview in Sitecore 6.2?

Tags: sitecore, preview

When i try to preview a page in my Sitecore solution, i get this asp.net error;

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

What could be causing this - it is only showing in preview mode, any other works fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [presentation components troubleshooting document](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/presentationcomponenttroubleshooting-a4.pdf), paragraph 5.2.